# spaces in between string stored in DB not shown on display

Tags: php, html, string

I have following string stored in my DB Table.

```
Tahseen A      test1   TEST TRANSFER LTD  BBP
```

As you can see it has multiple spaces in between words. But when get this string using following code

```
<td class="transactions"><?=$fullRS[$i]["columnName"]?></td>
```

The result on my php page shows its value as:

```
Tahseen A test1 TEST TRANSFER LTD BBP
```

You can see it removes extra spaces in between words of the string. Question is how can i show the same string that is stored i DB on php page?

Comment: PHP does not truncate space unless explicitly written. Could you do a `var_dump()` of `$fullRS[$i]["columnName"]`?

Comment: check the css definition `transactions` looks like its doing some sort of padding.

Comment: yes. The result set coming from DB has the same value which is stored in DB i.e. With spaces. But when the browser seems to truncating extra spaces.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class="transactions"><?php echo str_replace(" ","&nbsp;",$fullRS[$i]["columnName"]) ?></td>
```

Comment: thanks it did the work. But still don't know what is the actual problem. As per comment by @abhik css definition is not the problem.